# I am getting the following error - "column "A" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types"

Tags: ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012, ssrs-2014

I am following the SSIS overview video-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cPq9FXk-RA
I have a excel file that i want to import the contents from a SQL database.
I created a oledb source file and excel destination.
I am getting the following error -

> "column "A" cannot convert between Unicode and non-Unicode string data types"

Please help what to do

Comment: Column A in your source is most likely an nvarchar and in your destination a varchar (or viceversa). You can check this by going to the column tab on your Excel destionation and hover over the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add a Data Conversion transformation to convert string columns from non-Unicode (DT_STR) to Unicode (DT_WSTR) strings because Excel only recognizes Unicode.

You need to do this for all the string columns.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Porter